# How can I get know when I plug my headphones into the 3.5 interface?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, interrupt, udev

I want to write a small program in **C**: When I plug my headphones in my notebook, it should turn the volume lower. Then, when I remove headphone from my notebook, it should turn the volume back up.

I am using the `alsa` driver, and I know how to control the volume.

The question is: How to get notified, when the headphone gets plugged in?

Before I asked this question, I tried to use IRQ. I used `watch -d0.5 cat /proc/stat` to see if any interrupts are experienced by the system when I plug in or remove my headphone, and I see 8 interrupts. I don't know with IRQ is the right one so, I have no idea.

Comment: You probably want `udev`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ,  thanks, I have heared about it. So I add it as a tag. But I don't konw how to use it. Could you please give me some information about it? Thank you again. :)

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/8/udev http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

Comment: Madper if you get to solve your problem, post what you did as an answer and mark it as such. This is allowed in SO.

Comment: @RedX Ok, I will. But I haven't slove that~ :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you don't need to write any program. Alsamixer should let you specify the volume of the speaker and the volume of the headphones. You just set the headphones' volume a little lower, and that's all.